# soft Keyboard automatically changes from numeric to alphanumeric in Android 7

Tags: android

I have an edittext in my application that gets only numeric keys. It worked fine with a filter for the keys that the user enters and with numeric keyboard shows up when the user touches the edittext box. 
when I installed the app on android 7 device, the numeric keyboard shows up and after few seconds, it is hidden and an alphanumeric keyboard replaced it.
I need only numeric one!!
I assume that I need to "listen" to keyboard event and when I got any change in the keyboard type, I should act to change it back.
Anyone to tell me how to do it??!!

Comment: post your code what you have implemented

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file give below property to your edit text

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Comment: sometimes I need it to be Numeric and sometimes Alphanumeric so I change "input type" inside the code. well, I have a method to check which keyboard to show. in Android 6 and earlier versions, it works fine. when I need Numeric KB, I got it. In Android 7, although the Numeric KB is shown, it is suddenly, inconstantly changes to Alphanumeric